# How to create microsoft teams meet link using nodejs in web app

Tags: javascript, node.js, microsoft-graph-api

Problem statement : I am trying to create Microsoft teams meeting link using NodeJS without passing any tokens or granting permission. ( Or way to get token by asking the user to login to Microsoft account). But currently I am only getting ways which includes granting access in dashboard.

I am able to get token when I pass application id , tenant id etc. Which again give 403 forbidden may be because I am using my personal account. All I want a way to create meeting link without forcing to grant permission.

Comment: Looks like you are using [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to create onlinemeeting and this is not supported for [Personal Accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions). Give a try by [creating event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) which supports user calendar with personal accounts and use the onlinemeetingurl property.

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity Thanks for reply but it still need permisson

Comment: Yes, you need to give permission to let app pull your data for Microsoft Graph API. See this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference).

Comment: Moving this to Answer. Hi, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to create onlinemeeting and this is not supported for [Personal Accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions). Give a try by [creating event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) which supports user calendar with personal accounts and use the onlinemeetingurl property.

Yes, you need to give permission to let app pull your data for Microsoft Graph API. See this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference).